# Raphael JS - disable HREF in the drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I am using Rapheael to draw a control Dashboard. Right now I am adding a hyperlink object into the Dashboard editor. It is a text with the HREF attribute.
When I add the element and click on it, it opens the link. Is there some way to temporarly disable the link? 
When I click the other elements, it opens the property dialog. I would like that also with the Hyperlink object.

I've tried adding return:false, but didn't help:

```
obj.dblclick(function (event) {
        jQuery('##divProperties').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Try adding event.preventDefault() as the first line in the dblclick method.

Comment: @RobertLongson it worked! I've added event.preventDefault(); to obj.click Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning false is a way to cancel events with more traditional event binding, e.g.

```
obj.onclick = function() { return false }
```

or

```
<a onclick="return false;"></a>
```

But it doesn't work with jQuery event bindings.

To do that, you need to call the `.preventDefault()` method on the event object, which is passed to the event handler:

```
obj.dblclick(function (event) {
        jQuery('##divProperties').dialog('open');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

You may want to prevent default on the click event also if you're capturing double click so it doesn't get fired either.

Comment: yep, the second one works. I had to add it to obj.onclick, as that one is called first.